# Views of scholars on when to perform ruku' after sujud at-tilawa in prayer?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sajda

Especially in taraweeh prayer in the month of Ramadan we perform several times sujud at-tilawa if we meet a verse in which a sujud is required.

My question is let's say the sujud should be performed in the verse 17:107:

[image]

and I planed to go for ruku' right afterwards what are the views of scholars of the different schools of jurisprudence?

Is it permissible to go for sujud (perform the sujud) then stand up, then go down for ruku'?
Or should one at least recite one more verse before moving to ruku'?

In other words: Is there such a difference of opinion in this regards?